# CSS Putting a div under an absolute div

Tags: javascript, html, css

EDIT: Here's the live website: https://snidel.com/Form/Product/ProductDetail.aspx?shop=0&pid=SWFS195138&vid=&bid=SND01&cat=SKE001&swrd=

I am trying to put this green box div under the div. I am not sure why it is going in the middle and it looks like

[image]

What I am trying to accomplish is to be like
[image]

Here's the code below

```
<div class="block-btn">
  <div class="btn secondary store">
    <a href="" onclick="javascript:show_popup_window('/Form/Product/RealShopProductStockList.aspx?pid=SWFS195138&amp;vid=SWFS19513800321000', 630, 900, true, true, 'ProductRealShopStockList');return false;">
      <span class="ico"><img src="/Contents/ImagesPkg/common/ico_detail_store_01.svg" alt="" class="svg"></span>店舗在庫
    </a>
  </div>

  <div style="position: absolute;top: 34%;right:0;">
    <p style="font-size: 16px;display: inline-block;letter-spacing: 0.08em;font-weight: 400;font-family: futura-pt;">TOTAL

      <img src="/Contents/ImagesPkg/snidel/common/ico_favorite_02.svg" width="20" style="padding: 0 3px;">
      33

    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="greenbox" style="  
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  border: 15px solid green;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

I must not alter the style on the previous div, I can only edit styles under the green box div. I tried adjusting position and display but none of them works.

Comment: can you please share working demo ?

Comment: Remove `display:inline-block;` on the `<p>`. I would not use the HTML style attribute at all, actually, because it overrides CSS it will make your life difficult when you want to change your style. Just use external CSS.

Comment: I added the live website. Can you guys try to put a green box div below based on the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DIV `<div id="greenbox"></div></div>` are not properly closed.

Kindly use below code. You will get green box.

```css
#greenbox{ background:green; padding: 10px; clear:both;}
.store{width:50%; float:left;}
```

```html
<div class="block-btn">
  <div class="btn secondary store">
    <span class="ico"><img src="/Contents/ImagesPkg/common/ico_detail_store_01.svg" alt="" class="svg"></span>店舗在庫
    </div>

    <p style="margin:0;float:right;font-size: 16px;font-weight: 400;font-family: futura-pt;">TOTAL
      <img src="/Contents/ImagesPkg/snidel/common/ico_favorite_02.svg" width="20" style="padding: 0 3 px;">33
      </p>
    </div>

  <div id="greenbox"></div
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, I added the live site and edited the code can you check?

Answer (score 0):

Use display:block

Elements using display:block will always be placed beneath their older siblings, and above their younger siblings. In this case, the older sibling is "block-btn", so the green box appears beneath it.

```
<div id="greenbox" style="display: block; width: 200px; height: 75px; border: 5px solid green;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra closing tag  in your code

Answer (score 0):

```css
.store{width:45%; float:left; border:1px solid #000; padding:10px;}
```

```html
<div class="block-btn">
  <div class="btn secondary store">
    <a href="" onclick="javascript:show_popup_window('/Form/Product/RealShopProductStockList.aspx?pid=SWFS195138&amp;vid=SWFS19513800321000', 630, 900, true, true, 'ProductRealShopStockList');return false;">
      <span class="ico"><img src="/Contents/ImagesPkg/common/ico_detail_store_01.svg" alt="" class="svg"></span>店舗在庫
    </a>
  </div>

  <div style="width:45%; padding:10px; float:right;">
    <p style="float:right; font-size:16px; margin:0; display: inline-block;letter-spacing: 0.08em;font-weight: 400;font-family: futura-pt;">TOTAL

      <img src="/Contents/ImagesPkg/snidel/common/ico_favorite_02.svg" width="20" style="padding: 0 3px;">
      33

    </p><br><br>
  </div>
  <div id="greenbox" style=" 
  clear:both;
  display: block;
  border: 15px solid green;
  padding: 50px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the live site and edited the code can you check?

Comment: @makeymiolno I have updated the code that you provide, check now